# Firefox displays french characters incorreectly

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, character-encoding

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6, FireFox Quantum 57.0.1 (64-bit)

simply i created the following HTML page only has the following content 
( déménagement )

It's got displayed correctly on Chrome & Safari, how ever on FireFox it looks super weird ( deÌmeÌnagement )

Is it bug on firefix? is there a way to fix it by CSS or JS? or maybe character encoding

Comment: "Is it bug on firefix?" or is it more probable that you didn't specify the correct charset?

Comment: Anyway, you should provide your html in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the issue, it was because or copy/paste from a PDF file which sometime causes (BOM)

More about (BOM) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)